# NullReferenceException at Object.Equals(Object, Object)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, ilgenerator, object-equality

#### Situation

I'm generating wrappers by using the ILGenerator. I use `Object.Equals(Object, Object)` For the implementation of the equality compare of the wrapper fields. The debugger throws a `NullReferenceException` with the following stack trace.

```
at System.Object.Equals(Object objA, Object objB)
at HIDDEN.StateTransitionWrapper.op_Equality(StateTransitionWrapper , StateTransitionWrapper )
at HIDDEN.StateTransitionWrapper.Equals(Object )
at System.Object.Equals(Object objA, Object objB)
at HIDDEN.StationEventCompositeWrapper.op_Equality(StationEventCompositeWrapper , StationEventCompositeWrapper )
at HIDDEN.StationEventCompositeWrapper.Equals(Object )
at System.Object.Equals(Object objA, Object objB)
at HIDDEN.CompareResult..ctor(Object object0, Object object1, String fieldName) 
....
```

#### Object.Equals(Object, Object) - Disassembly

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    return objA == objB || (objA != null && objB != null && objA.Equals(objB));
}
```

As you can see in the disassembly it's impossible that any `NullReferenceException` can occur because it won't reach the part where the method call is.

#### Possible problems

As i said the hole code is generated by using the ILGenerator and i think this could the only possible source for the error. The caller has only value types inside, so it's not even possible that the object is null.

#### Calling IL-Code

```
IL_0040: ldarg.0
IL_0041: call instance valuetype [HIDDEN]HIDDEN.StationStateType HIDDEN.StateTransitionWrapper::get_StationState()
IL_0046: box [mscorlib]System.Object
IL_004b: ldarg.1
IL_004c: call instance valuetype [HIDDEN]HIDDEN.StationStateType HIDDEN.StateTransitionWrapper::get_StationState()
IL_0051: box [mscorlib]System.Object
IL_0056: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
```

Comment: How is the equality operator implemented for the type of the objects used?

Comment: @ken2k Both objects in StateTransitionWrapper are value types.

Comment: Is StateTransitionWrapper a value type?

Comment: @AndreLoker No, its a class. You need to know that `HIDDEN.StateTransitionWrapper.op_Equality(StateTransitionWrapper , StateTransitionWrapper )` successful calls the `Object.Equals(Object, Object)`-method, so the error happens there.

Comment: @FelixK. I was wondering if one of the StateTransitionWrapper instances could be null and for some reason (inlining, error in the generated IL code etc.) only the stack trace isn't correct.

Comment: Impossible to get a NullRef in Object.Equals. Its even shown in example on MSDN. Sure that stacktrace is right? Do we miss a stack frame?

Comment: @AndreLoker I'm checking the references before calling the Object.Equals method.

Comment: MSDN example: Object.Equals("Tom", "Carol") => False
Object.Equals("Tom", "Tom") => True
Object.Equals(null, "Tom") => False
Object.Equals("Carol", null) => False
Object.Equals(null, null) => True

Comment: @BlueM I know, but it happens. I don't know the reason but it happens 100% at Object.Equals. I checked the stacktrace about 10 times because i can't belive it. Anyway i'm comparing value types not reference. They should never be null.

Comment: Is it possible that this statement `(objA != null && objB != null && objA.Equals(objB));` is processing in a different order than what you expect. I.E. Is it trying to evaluate objA.Equals(objB) before determining that objA is not null?

Comment: Its predetermined by the language which order is taken. Its defined in the specification. There is no random processing of that line.

Comment: Does `StationStateType` override the `Equals` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the `box` instruction specify the type that you're trying to box?

For example, shouldn't you be using...

```
box System.Int32  // or whatever
```

...rather than...

```
box System.Object
```

Comment: Not if you are casting to a object to match the `Object.Equal(Object, Object)` which requires 2 objects.

Comment: I believe @LukeH is correct.  The IL `box [HIDDEN]HIDDEN.StationStateType` would return an `object`. By using `box System.Object` you're saying "box this object to an object". I think that strips the actual type of the value being boxed. I don't know why that would result in the exception though.

Comment: You are correct, even when Mike's answer is describing the behaviour a little bit better i give you the credits.

Answer (score 2):

The box *typeTok* opcode (ECMA-355 Partition III, section 4.2) takes *val* from the stack and converts it to *obj*. If *typeTok* is a reference type, the `box` instruction returns *val* **unchanged** [emphasis added] as *obj*. When *typeTok* is a value type (at least a non-nullable one), on the other hand, `box` creates a new object and copies the data from *val* into the new object.

As @LukeH points out, the IL above is using the command `box [mscorlib]System.Object` when it should use `box [HIDDEN]HIDDEN.StationStateType`.  The latter will still return an `object` which will be valid for the `Object.Equals(Object, Object)` call. I believe the current call is returning an invalid object that is causing the `NullReferenceException`.